# Operator is not working in keyword type field in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "activity_type": {
        "query": "video Post",
        "operator": "OR"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above query is not searching records in elastic I have data for both video and Post,the above above query is working on text type of fields but not working on Keyword type of field.

Comment: What is the mapping type of field `activity_type`? Is it a text field or keyword field?

Comment: activity type is keyword field

Answer (score 0):

Keyword fields are not analysed. This means that on each document, the value of that field is kept as is, rather than broken down into several terms.
This effectively means you cannot search that field against a single term. Only search for the entire field value.

For example, if you have the `keyword` mapping for field **name**, and a document with:

```json
{
// rest of the document
"name": "Foo Bar Baz"
// rest of the document
}
```

If your search is:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "Foo Bar",
        "operator": "OR"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

that document will not be retrieved.
Your query would need to be `"query": "Foo Bar Baz"`.

A possible solution for your problem can be to index that field both as `text` field and also as `keyword` field. You could do that with something like:

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "activity_type": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What this is doing is artificially creating the field `.raw` **within** your normal field `activity_type`, where the former has the `text` type and the later the `keyword` type.

Then your search would work, **and** you would still get the benefit of the `keyword` mapping under the artificially create field `activity_type.raw`.

Comment: To achieve This I have created a custom analyzer like below :{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": ","
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: It works on keyword field but not text field What need to be changed it so that it will work also for text field

Comment: So you changed the analyzer for field `activity_type` to your custom analyser and now it works for `keyword` fields but no longer works for `text` fields? (originally you said it worked for `text` fields but not `keyword` fields)

Comment: Yes Orginallly I am not using any analyzer

Comment: After Changing to custom analyzer it works for Field

Comment: I would expect your original search query to work **now** for all the fields with your custom analyzer. Is that not the case?

Comment: Yes with custom analyzer it now works for all fields With Keyword type but custom analyzer not working correctly with text field, So what I need to change in custom analyzer so that custom analyzer can work with text type of field also

Comment: What do you mean by not working with with `text` fields? Are you using the same query? What is the value on field `activity_type` of the document that you would expect to be retrieved?